# Css and Javascript failing to load in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Trying to add a slider to an html page in my django project, but css and javascript is not loading. Because of this instead of the slider being an actual slider ie. images sliding across, I get a vertical line of pictures. These are the errors i am getting in my browser console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slider.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at slider.js:1
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
countdown.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at updateClock (countdown.js:26)
    at initializeClock (countdown.js:36)
    at countdown.js:41
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slider.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the structure of my static folder

```
static
-->second
---->css
       >app
         slider.css
---->js
       >app
         slider.css
```

my html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'second/css/app/slider.css' %}">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'second/js/app/slider.js' %}"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Our  Partners</h3>
        <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
   </section>
</div>
```

My javascript (slider.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

and css (slider.css):

```
h3{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the codepen with this slider working 
https://codepen.io/emms21/pen/eYpgMwz

Comment: You Should Add Jquery CDN Before Slider.js. The order Matters. Slider.js is dependent on Jquery. So You Should Load Jquery Before SliderJs

Comment: @HarishST thanks, I have added jquery CDN before slider.js but still getting the same errors

Comment: Please check your SliderJs path. It's giving 404 Means The file is not found in the path. Ensure the file is available in the Path Specified.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to include the jQuery CDN.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Add this line to your html file.

Comment: Thanks, I had included the jQuery CDN, will update the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

In script tag add attribute
type = "text/javascript"